# Is this a SSIS use case? (new to SSIS)

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, evaluation, use-case

I am currently starting the initial design for a solution which is basically doing some data transformation from one file. The basic procedure is like this:

- The application gets one file per day copied to a network location (size is currently unknown)
- The file should then be copied to another location as a backup
- Then the file should be processed: The format is pretty easy to parse and nothing fancy in there
- The file contents are to be written to a database (sql server)
- If everything went well, the original file should be deleted (the backup copy should be kept)

My boss is repeatedly suggesting to use SSIS for this, but i have never used it before, so i am not sure if i can implement this purely with SSIS, especially the actions that should be taken on the file. Also, i am not sure if its a good decision to use SSIS if i dont really know how to work with it.

Is that a typical SSIS use case? Can this be implemented using pure SSIS?

Comment: Yes, Yes, Yes and yes. This is a typical ETL process.

Comment: Yes. but question is off topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a 'classic' ETL scenario and you can certainly do it all in SSIS, the only question is whether you want to or not. With the exception of loading data from a flat file into the database, the steps you describe would probably be easier to implement in Perl, PowerShell or whatever other scripting language you prefer.

Having said that, SSIS does offer some very nice features (logging, configuration, debugging, workflow) and if you might expand the process in future to include extra steps then SSIS is a great way to tie the whole process together and control the execution of those steps.

Personally, I would decide based on the file processing. If it's a simple CSV file, I would probably use SSIS; if it requires regexes or other text parsing, I would do it all in an external script. Or possibly mix the two, and do the parsing in an external script and call it from the SSIS package.

And if  you're interested in learning SSIS then this is obviously a good opportunity to start, especially since your boss can't complain about you spending time on 'playing around' with something new.